# Set Theory - Subset Exercises

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've just started learning about set theory and am doing some exercises online although it is not taking me to the answers page to review.

Are these correct?

[Image of set theory excercises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjKHD.png)

Comment: The first one is wrong but the rest is correct.  The element $3$ is not an element of the set so $\{3\} \not \subset A$.  The *set* $\{3\}$ is an element of A so $\{\{3\}\} \subset A$.

Comment: Isn't it saying, {3} is a subset of A rather than an element of?

Comment: @AKL012 $\{3\}$ is an element of $A$ but $3$ is not. This means that $\{\{3\}\}$ is a subset of $A$ but $\{3\}$ is not.

Comment: Yes,  It is saying that $\{3\}$ is a subset of A.  Which is wrong.

Comment: Okay I understand, thanks

Comment: Let $pookypie = \{3\}$.  Then $A = \{1,2, pookypie, 4,5\}$.  $\{3\} \not \subset \{1,2, pookypie, 4,5\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is false, since $\{3\}$ is a an element of $A$ but not a subset. For some $X$ to be a subset of set $Y$ every element of $X$ must be an element of $Y$, but here we have $3$ is an element of $\{3\}$ but not a member of $A$.

This is the same reason to why the 5th one is also false as you've put, since $3 \in \{1,2,3\}$ not $3 \notin A$.

Otherwise your answers are correct.